# Neo4j group relationships between node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to retrieve all relationships between 2 nodes grouped and I currently have this code, but the issue is I get multiple rows for each pair

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE n.name = '${query}' or 
      m.name = '${query}' 
RETURN n, m, COUNT(r.aa) as aa, COUNT(r.bb) as bb
```

For example if I have **x-aa[1,2,3]->y** and **x-bb[1,2,3]->y** I will get 2 rows
x, y, 3, 0
x, y, 0, 3
and what I want is to get 1 row with the combination of the 2
x, y, 3, 3

Comment: What if both relationships have `aa` and `bb`?

Comment: Use real cypher parameters, not string replacements.

Comment: @MichaelHunger what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `RETURN` clause uses the aggregation function `COUNT`, it should return a single row for each pair of `n` and `m` nodes. Therefore, I suspect your query actually matches 2 different pairs, not a single pair.

Comment: Yes it returns 2 different pairs, as I show in the example. The thing is I need a query that returns them combined